# Express JS / MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have some code that takes care of a register post form on a page. Every time it gets passed by the validation and by the seems of it ( tested with console.logs ) it moves to the code that should save a new user. However my app just goes into constant refreshing and doesnt stop. The code is basically copied and pasting from brad traversy's tutorial pretty much, so no reason it shouldnt work. I thought maybe im not connected to mongoDB but the console.log statement that goes through says otherwise.

users.js ( post request handler )

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const {
        name,
        email,
        password,
        password2
    } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
        errors.push({
            msg: 'Please enter all fields'
        });
    }

    if (password != password2) {
        errors.push({
            msg: 'Passwords do not match'
        });
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({
            msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters'
        });
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2
        });
    } else {
        User.findOne({
            email: email
        }).then(user => {
            if (user) {
                errors.push({
                    msg: 'Email already exists'
                });
                res.render('register', {
                    errors,
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    password2
                });
            } else {
                const newUser = new User({
                    name,
                    email,
                    password
                });

                bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        newUser.password = hash;
                        newUser
                            .save()
                            .then(user => {
                                req.flash(
                                    'success_msg',
                                    'You are now registered and can log in'
                                );
                                res.redirect('/users/login');
                            })
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

app.js ( removed the URI key for obvious reasons. Mongoose should connect as the console.log statement is going through, sometimes slow however)

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;


// db config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// connect to mongo
mongoose.connect('', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'));


// ejs
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))


// routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

app.listen(port, console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

user.js ( my user model schema )

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

EDIT: I am not getting this error code in my terminal, but it goes away if i refresh the server

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1449:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\robolowski\Desktop\portfolio\ExpressLoginApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\robolowski\Desktop\portfolio\ExpressLoginApp\app.js:33:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8000
}
```

Comment: what's the error that you got at the console? I saw variable `db` is not passed in `mongoose.connect`

Comment: @kedarsedai Well it used to be. But apparently its type was "undefined" so i just inserted the text as it is instead. In `config/keys` i have an object `db = { MongoURI: "Insert key here"}`

Comment: `mongoose.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'));` it should look like this

Comment: @kedarsedai Thats literally what i have already. i just removed db and put the raw text what the variable db was anyway.

Comment: is there any error then?

Comment: @kedarsedai nooo. I think you misread what i said. It says im connected to mongoDB, basically the console.log statement works. This should confirm im connected. In my `users.js` The code gets to the second `else` statement and runs.(i tested with a console.log) But it is not making a new "user" and my webpage is just constantly refreshing.

Comment: did you exports router?

Comment: @kedarsedai `module.exports = router;` Yes. I forgot to add it in the file

Comment: Try one thing that change port number from 8000 to something else say 3000 and check if work or not

Comment: @kedarsedai Nope. Oh btw i literally just copied every line of code from the tutorial github. No errors in console. Im 90% the mongoDB credentials are right( even tried using old linking system ) and my page just loads/refreshes whatever you wanna call it forever EDIT: i think its mongoose side of things thats causing the issue. It says after i post the form in console that it couldnt connect to any servers on your cluster. That means im connecting and the code is 100% right soooo.

Comment: @kedarsedai It just fixed itself. I dont know how , or why. Im guessing mongoose server is messed up idk ?

Comment: It was solved without doing any code changes and if it was the error that you have mentioned it means that you have closed any application on your PC which is running on same port number because error clearly mentions that address already in use.so may be again it will reproduce when you open that application

Comment: @DimplePatel i dont think i did open any? I mean it was non stop working on this issue lol, one instance of localhost open so im confused